# Javascript object properties undefined after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I've made an ajax call which has returned a json string from a .Net JsonConvert.SerializeObject() call, the json is automatically parsed into an object at the browser but I am currently unable to access the properties without "undefined" being returned.

My current json string being returned is (removed bulk of byte array):

```
"[{\"filename\":\"\",\"size\":6,\"csize\":\"       5.85 KB\",\"extfile\":\"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDA....AAAAAAAAAAAf//Z\"}]"
```

I've validated this and it's all fine.

My javascript is:

```
function GetItemImage() {
    let kditem = $("#txtItem").text();
    let url = GetUrl();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "kditem": kditem
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                $("#ImgItem").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,'" + data.extfile + "'");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have made sure it is definitely an object. I've tried accessing as data.extfile, data["extfile"], passing extfile in as a byte array and then accessing that but it is always coming up as "undefined". In desperation I even tried accessing indexes, iterating through the object etc. and still nothing.

I have a feeling that there is an issue in the json string which is preventing it from converting properly but I can't see it as I haven't worked much with json. Could someone point out where I'm going wrong?

**Solution**

Javascript was parsing the response into an object with a single property "data.d", parsed data.d and that created the object correctly.

```
function GetItemImage() {
    let kditem = $("#txtItem").text();
    let url = GetUrl();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "kditem": kditem
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null && data.d != null) {
                let imgData = JSON.parse(data.d);
                $("#ImgItem").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + imgData[0].extfile);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what about `console.log(data)`, what does it show?

Comment: ... also `console.log("data type is: " + (typeof data));`

Comment: if the json string that you get is `data`, basically it is an array, not an object.

Comment: Your `data` is an array of object. So you should use `data[0].extfile`

Comment: console.log returns: {d: "[{"filename":"","size":6,"csize":"       5.85 KB",…AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAf//Z"}]"}

typeof returns: object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically if the `string` that you pasted is the response (data), when using `JSON.parse()` it converts into an array , so you should use it like that.

```js
const stringResponse = "[{\"filename\":\"\",\"size\":6,\"csize\":\"       5.85 KB\",\"extfile\":\"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDA....AAAAAAAAAAAf//Z\"}]"


const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(stringResponse);

console.log(parsedResponse)

const entry = parsedResponse[0];

console.log(entry.extfile)
```

so basically, you need to do:

```
data[0].extfile
```

Since the console.log(data) statement returns:

```
{d: "[{"filename":"","size":6,"csize":" 5.85 KB",…AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAf//Z"}]"}
```

The data you are actually trying to obtain is contained in a JSON string contained in the d property of the data received.  If you were to parse the string and then access the extfile property you would have your data:

```
var actualData= JSON.parse(data.d);

var extfile = actualData[0].extfile;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse!

Unfortunately I tried that and get "Cannot read property 'extfile' of undefined".

Comment: console.log returns: {d: "[{"filename":"","size":6,"csize":"       5.85 KB",…AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAf//Z"}]"}

typeof returns: object

Comment: it looks like the response is an object with a string d that contains a string representation of an Array that contains the object you are looking for:  JSON.parse(d)[0].extfile seems an odd packet of data.

Comment: @HarryChilinguerian Life saver, you got me there. The moment you said it's an object with a string it clicked! Thanks!

Comment: @TheAngryYorkshireman Thanks this response from Prince Hernanadez asking you to console log the data and seeing it was what lead to the response.  Sometimes we forget to go the analytical route and try to guess at the solution, I would upvote or accpet Prince Hernandez response since it was the best route to a solution.

Comment: @HarryChilinguerian thank you so much for the suggestion, you also nailed it!

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this will help but here it is:

Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Also the data is an Array, maybe grab the first object in the array data[0].extfile.

I'm thinking it maybe reworked as such:

```
function GetItemImage() {
    let kditem = $("#txtItem").text();
    let url = GetUrl();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            "kditem": kditem
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }).done(function(data){
        if (data != null) {
            $("#ImgItem").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64,'" + 
            data[0].extfile + "'");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Love an explanation for the down vote, helps me improve answers, thanks.